# PHP/Composer include and path-handling

Tags: php, include, composer-php, webserver

i have got a local installation of xampp with wordpress.
xampp -> htdocs -> mywordpress -> composerproject
[content of composerproject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Rmqm.png)

I am using a wordpressplugin to include php in articles of wordpress like this

> include('../composerproject/recanalyst/test.php');

Everything works fine on a local maschine with xampp an the same wordpress both are working with php 7.1.

But when i deploy the same on my webspace with following settings:
[paths of webspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFYZF.png)

```
define('ROOTPATH', __DIR__);
echo ROOTPATH;
require ROOTPATH . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use RecAnalyst\RecordedGame;

$filename = ROOTPATH . '/test.mgz';


$rec = new RecordedGame($filename);// This line 12 doesnt work
```

Error line 12

```
Uncaught Error: Class 'RecAnalyst\RecordedGame' not found in /var/www/vhosts/myhoster.net/httpdocs/recanalyst/test.php:12 Stack trace: #0
```

Composerproject on github:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/goto-bus-stop/recanalyst/blob/master/examples/tabbed-native/index.php)

Answer (score 1):

Can be closed. My webhoster is running with php 7.1 but their cli was running with 5.3.3. So i had installed with putty an old version of composer without recognizing it. Changing the CLI to 7.1 was the solution.